# Travelling on two different Visas

Tags: visas, international-travel

I am currently in USA with a student visa issued in my home Country (A). This Visa is valid till Aug 2021. I also have an Italian Long term Visa which starts from Nov 1st 2018. I want to visit country A and then come back to USA and then leave to Italy.

Could you please tell me if this is possible?

Comment: When you say "come back to USA," for what purpose will you be returning? To continue your studies? Do you have a valid I-20?

Comment: @ZachLipton Yes. I have a valid i20 signed for travel.

Comment: What makes you think you can’t?

Comment: I am worried that I might be stopped at Customs as they see a long term visa in Italy. The long term Italian visa is for a PhD.

Comment: Only one man's opinion, but my guess is that item - as such - would not be an issue.  For example, I have many, many visas for all sorts of places, and I've not seen that "cause a problem" - in itself.

Comment: Will you have completed your studies in the US when you leave for your trip to country A?

Answer (score 2):

To enter on a visa, you must be entering the country for one of the purposes that the visa permits. For an F visa that is your studies. You'll be admitted for the remainder of the duration of your studies, OPT, etc. Having another visa for another country is completely irrelevant. But if you are not entering to study, then you might be refused.